# Rails 5 - config.assets.compile should be true - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing Rails 5 application and use assets pipeline.
It work well in development mode, but if I try to run it in production mode, it can't load images & styles correctly.
I checked and found that it is because

> config.assets.compile = false

in config/environments/production.rb

Unless I set it true, it doesn't work at all.
I know live compilation isn't good for production, what is solution?

Answer (score 16):

There are two options related to serving assets within a Rails server:

### Asset compilation

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

refers to asset compilation. That is, whether Rails should recompile the assets when it detects that a new version of the source assets is there. In development, you want to have it set to `true`, so that your styles get compiled when you edit the css files. With the next request, Rails will automatically recompile the assets. On production, you usually want to set it to `false` and handle asset compilation during deployment. For this, you have to run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
```

Usually, if you deploy using Capistrano, it takes care of that.

### Asset serving

The second option related to assets is

```
config.public_file_server.enabled
```

This describes whether it is Rails that should serve the compiled files from the `public/assets` directory. In development, you want that, so it's true by default. In production, you usually don't want to fire up your web server to serve the logo image or a css file, so you probably compile the assets and then host them separately (for example, on a CDN like cloudfront). If you still want them to be served in production, you can launch Rails with:

```
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails server
```

Answer (score 1):

Precompile your assets first.

Run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` to generate your stylesheets and js files in your public directory.

Comment: I already precompiled by using that statement which generated files in public directory. But same issue